# Sunspot: can't use "order_by" on text fields?

Tags: ruby, solr, sunspot

If I try to use `order_by` on a text field I get: "no field configured with name title".

Works fine on fields of type "string". So I end up using a workaround like:

```
searchable do 
  text :title

  string :title_sortable do 
    title
  end
end
```

Is there any reason why we cannot `order_by` on text fields?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is by Solr design.  Text fields are tokenized. Sorting on a tokenized field does not make sense.

Consider the following two white space tokenized fields in two different docs.

"quick fire ammo"
"black bear"

When you sort them in ascending order, the first one should not appear before the second, just because it has the word "ammo" in it.

That is why, the sortable fields should be defined as String.

Comment: Ah, I see that I was using text_general (which is apparently orderable?) for my title field back when I was using SolrJ. After converting to Ruby/Sunspot, I made this a text field. Thanks.